# How can i execute sc create command through exec os/exec?

Tags: go, service, cmd, exec, sc

How can i execute my `sc` command through `exec.Command`?

**Code:**

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "sc", "create", "Simpler", "binpath="+os.Getenv("APPDATA")+"\\Simpler\\cc.exe", "displayname=MY SERVICE");
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true};
out, _ := cmd.Output(); fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This i get in command prompt (open command prompt in current command prompt -_-):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd c:\prog\logs

c:\prog\logs>go build test.go

c:\prog\logs>test.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\prog\logs>

c:\prog\logs>
```

Followed command cannot be executed. I do not get anything! Where is the problem?

Command been started if i execute `sc.exe` in current command prompt but not started if i execute in new command prompt.

That is if i remove first argument `"cmd.exe"` my program succesfully execute with excepted result. But how to execute in a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the immediate problem is that what you do is not how `cmd.exe` should be told to execute an external command—in order to make it execute one, you should pass `cmd.exe` either the `/C` or `/K` command-line option,
like in

```
C:\>cmd.exe /C sc whatever sc_arg1 sc_arg2 ...
```

What you observe with your call is that `cmd.exe` ignores
the rest of the arguments you pass to it and just runs—that's
exactly what you're observing.

Start with studying the output of `cmd.exe /?` and the
built-in Windows help system to get better idea of how it works.

The next problem is that there is absolutely no reason to make `cmd.exe` involved in running `sc`—just run `sc` directly rather than jumping around `cmd.exe` to make it execute `sc`.

The next problem is that you're ignoring the error value returned
by the call to `os/exec.Cmd.Output`. Since Go (luckily) does not
have exceptions, handing all error values is of paramount
importance—it's better to ignore everything else but not
errors.
If you're writing highly-experimental code, you might
*start* with a dumb helper like

```
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

and then roll like

```
out, err := cmd.Output()
check(err)
```

This approach is not for production-grade code, but allows
for faster code churn when experimenting.

You might also consider calling directly into Win32 API to
manage services as it will make error handling substantially
easier.

Comment: Note that you don't need `cmd.exe` at all in your case.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late and not really about running sc.exe. While the problem of using SC.exe is solved in the answer @kostix provides, I see that you are trying to create a service of a Go application and consider this an XY problem.

It is not likely that a single call of `sc.exe` would successfully create a windows service. However, there is a lib to help: `golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc`.

There is also an example on github: https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/svc/example

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

```
   func main() {
        data, _ := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "sc", "qc", "serviceName").Output()
        fmt.Println(string(data))
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS                                                                         
                                                                                                        
SERVICE_NAME: serviceName                                                                                  
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS                                                      
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START                                                             
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL                                                                 
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\serviceName
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :                                                                            
        TAG                : 0                                                                          
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Display Server                                                           
        DEPENDENCIES       : Tcpip                                                                      
                           : Afd                                                                        
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```